# How to get objectSid value programmaticaly from Active Directory?

Tags: command-line, azure-active-directory

I'm searching for a way to get the objectSid value for an Active Directory Group programmaticaly.
I found a solution to get this value using powerShell :

```
Get-WMIObject win32_group -filter "name='WIKI_ADMIN'"|select sid
```

However what i want is to do is to get this value not from a windows machine, but from a distant Linux one.

I found a tool "adcli" that offer some fonctionnality on an AD (create user, group, ...) but no way to get the groupSid info.

Is there another tool, solution, script to get a such value ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution using ldapsearch command line :

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -h ldap_url -D 'cn=user name,OU=users,OU=myOU,DC=myou,DC=com' -w my_password -b 'CN=the_group_name,OU=users,OU=myOU,DC=myou,DC=com' -s sub '(objectClass=group)' | grep objectSid
```

And this gave me something like that :

```
objectSid:: AQUsAAAAAAUVAAAA5BLIGcudyeZ/J0pqbvoAxA==
```

However the value is in binary and base64 encoded, i found a script in another forum that decoded it successfully :

```
!/bin/bash
# Base-64 encoded objectSid

OBJECT_ID="AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAPWW1S5rojK4mDAiG5BAAAA=="

OBJECT_ID=$1


# Decode it, hex-dump it and store it in an array

G=($(echo -n $OBJECT_ID | base64 -d -i | hexdump -v -e '1/1 " %02X"'))



# SID in HEX

# SID_HEX=${G[0]}-${G[1]}-${G[2]}${G[3]}${G[4]}${G[5]}${G[6]}${G[7]}-${G[8]}${G[9]}${G[10]}${G[11]}-${G[12]}${G[13]}${G[14]}${G[15]}-${G[16]}${G[17]}${G[18]}${G[19]}-${G[20]}${G[21]}${G[22]}${G[23]}-${G[24]}${G[25]}${G[26]}${G[27]}${G[28]}



# SID Structure: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962011.aspx

# LESA = Little Endian Sub Authority

# BESA = Big Endian Sub Authority

# LERID = Little Endian Relative ID

# BERID = Big Endian Relative ID



BESA2=${G[8]}${G[9]}${G[10]}${G[11]}

BESA3=${G[12]}${G[13]}${G[14]}${G[15]}

BESA4=${G[16]}${G[17]}${G[18]}${G[19]}

BESA5=${G[20]}${G[21]}${G[22]}${G[23]}

BERID=${G[24]}${G[25]}${G[26]}${G[27]}${G[28]}



LESA1=${G[2]}${G[3]}${G[4]}${G[5]}${G[6]}${G[7]}

LESA2=${BESA2:6:2}${BESA2:4:2}${BESA2:2:2}${BESA2:0:2}

LESA3=${BESA3:6:2}${BESA3:4:2}${BESA3:2:2}${BESA3:0:2}

LESA4=${BESA4:6:2}${BESA4:4:2}${BESA4:2:2}${BESA4:0:2}

LESA5=${BESA5:6:2}${BESA5:4:2}${BESA5:2:2}${BESA5:0:2}

LERID=${BERID:6:2}${BERID:4:2}${BERID:2:2}${BERID:0:2}



LE_SID_HEX=${LESA1}-${LESA2}-${LESA3}-${LESA4}-${LESA5}-${LERID}



# Initial SID value which is used to construct actual SID

SID="S-1"



# Convert LE_SID_HEX to decimal values and append it to SID as a string

IFS='-' read -ra ADDR <<< "${LE_SID_HEX}"

for OBJECT in "${ADDR[@]}"; do

  SID=${SID}-$((16#${OBJECT}))

done
echo ${SID}
```

and i got this :

S-1-48378511622149-21-432542436-3871972811-1783244671-3288398446

:)